# How do I create a copy of an object?

Tags: asp.net

I have a object named `post` and I declare a new variable named `newPost` as type `post` object and then

> var newPost = post

but when I Modify any properties of `post` object, that Modified Influences properties of `newPost` object.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: My recommendation is that you do a little homework first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide some way to clone the object. As other commenter said, you are just referencing the same object. See this StackOverflow Question (first answer) for details [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is one of a number of possible things.  Here are a couple for consideration.

1. Implement IClonable and do `var
   newPost = post.Clone();`
2. Have a constructor on the class that has
   another instance as a paramenter,
   then copy the properties from the
   instance passed in to the new
   instance.  i.e. `var newPost = new
   Post(post);`

One gotcha to look out for, you probably will want to do what's known as a [*deep clone* or *deep copy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) of the object, so that if your class has any object properties the two instances aren't pointing to the same reference for their properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely basic question, and I can't write a book on it...

But that's exactly how it is supposed to work. You are setting 'reference' variables; `newPost` and `post` both refer to the exact same object which is a `class` and therefore a Reference type, so you should expect that all changes to one also affect the other.

It sounds like you need to pick up a good basic .NET programming book, and pay particular attention to the differences between Value and Reference types.

The 'solution' is to create a new object and set/copy the individual members of the old object to the new one, but I fear that solution will not serve you too long before you dig some more into things.